# Meteor code must always run within a Fiber

Tags: meteor

A Meteor code is producing this error

```js
packages\meteor.js:1260
(STDERR)     throw new Error("Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. " +

(STDERR) Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
```

Here is the code, Isn't running within a Fiber. then why the error? and how to fix it? Please. Thanks

```js
// ON THE SERVER

//methods.js
import {collectData} from './ad/server/logic';
Meteor.mothods({
  'collectData'(source, instrument) {
    instrument.forEach(function(item, index) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        collectData(item)
      }, 5000 * (index + 1));
    });
  },
})

//logic.js
import WebSocket from "ws";

async function collectData(instrument){
  let dt = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
  try {
    scrap(instrument, dt)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('scrap error: ', error)    
  }
}

function scrap(instrument, dt){
  //...
  socket.onmessage = function(message) {
    //...
    insertScrapedData(instrument, scrapedData)
  }
};

function insertScrapedData(VAL, scrapedData){
  if(VAL == 'XXX'){
    Meteor.bindEnvironment((callback) => {
      insertDocument('XXX', scrapedData, callback); // <<<<<<<<<< THE ERROR LINE <<<<<<<<<<
    }, (err) => {
      console.error('insert error', err);
    });
  }
}

function insertDocument(VAL, doc, callback) {
  if(VAL=='XXX) xxxCol.insert(doc, callback);
}
export {collectData}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both your `setTimeout` handler and the `socket.onmessage` callback break out from the fiber. You need to wrap these callbacks with `Meteor.bindEnvironment`, just like you did inside `insertScrapedData`. Basically, once you are outside the fiber, you can't get back in, so the `Meteor.bindEnvironment` in `insertScrapedData` is not enough. You need to make sure you never even leave it.

Since `setTimeout` is, of course, a very commonly needed method, Meteor actually provides a ready-to-go version you can use without bindEnvironment:
https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setTimeout